# Can I tell Firefox somehow to open a specific site always in mobile size?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has a built in toggle for desktop/mobile size view: Ctrl+Shift+M

I usually browse every site full size, but there is a certain site which I want to browse in a mobile sized view.

Is there a way to tell Firefox to open that site always in mobile view (like when I push Ctrl+Shift+M), so I don't have to switch the view manually?

Comment: What about if you [have an intermediate page that opens the new window with the size you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157204/278545)? Is that sufficient? All you'd need is a basic html page with the link in it.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks, though not really convenient, because then I have to manage a separate window instead of just another tab. So I'd prefer a solution which could manage to do  it in a tab.

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, until a proper solution is found, I settled on Autohotkey where I set up a hotkey which when pressed, switches to firefox, opens a new tab, and switches to mobile mode:

```
  WinActivate ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
  winwaitactive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
  send ^t
  sleep 500
  send ^+m
```